# React: how can I access the methods of the class that generates JSX?

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I have the following classes:

```
class App {
    constructor() {
        super();         
        this.pawns[3][2] = this.getRegPawn(PAWN.BLUE);
        debugger;   /// HERE !!!
    }

    getRegPawn(pawnType) {
        return <RegularPawn pawnType={pawnType}/>;
    }    
}

    class RegularPawn extends AbstractPawn {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }

        isBasicMove() {
            ...
        }

        isStrikeMove() {
           ....
            }
            return false;
        }

        render() {
            const _this = this;
            switch (this.props.pawnType) {
                case PAWN.BLUE:
                    pawn = <div className="bluePawn" ref = {() => {return _this}}></div>;
                    break;
                case PAWN.RED:
                    pawn = <div className="redPawn" ref = {() => {return _this}}></div>;
                    break;
            }
            return pawn;
        }
    }
```

My intention is to access the methods in class RegularPawn by accessing this.pawns[3][2].

The object stored in this.pawns[3][2] is:

[image]

I tried: 
this.pawns[3][2].isBasicMove()

this.pawns[3][2].props.isBasicMove()

this.pawns[3][2].ref.isBasicMove()

this.pawns[3][2].props.ref.isBasicMove()

and none of them succeeded. Do you know what can help me?

Comment: Have you tried to initiate variable outside of JSX? `const _this = this;` and pass it to `param3` ?

Comment: tried. It didn't help

Comment: This should work, so the issue might be the value if `this` in the render function. If its fine you can also try passing it a function bound to your component: `param3={()={return this}}` and use it in the child like `this.props.param3()`.

Comment: Why do you want to assign the instance of the class to a param? Which is the purpose?

Comment: @Ankari, it still doesn't work.

Comment: What is the value of `this` in the render method? You can log it before the return.

Comment: looks like JSX object. It's not null.

Comment: Can you show how you try to access it inside the component you pass it to?

Comment: I edited the question. I hope it's clearer.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use functions from the child components you will need to use references instead of the return value of the `createElement` call from react (which is the return value of a JSX tag).

You can pass the ref callback to child components and use the returned value to assign the pawn matrix.

Here is a simple example how to use it versus what you are trying to do:

The Alert1 Button behaves as you use it, it won't work, on the other hand Alert2 button is using `ref` which is the way to go.

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
 constructor() {
  super();
   this.child = <Child ref={(ref) => {this.child2 = ref;}} />
   console.log(this.child);
  }
  
  childAllert1() {
  this.child.allert();
  }
  
  childAllert2() {
  this.child2.allert();
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
    Hello {this.props.name}
    <button onClick={this.childAllert1.bind(this)} >Alert1</button>
    <button onClick={this.childAllert2.bind(this)} >Alert2</button>
    {this.child}
    </div>);
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {

  allert() {
  alert("called");
  }
  render() {
    return <div>Hello
    </div>;
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: In what file/class the statement ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
should be placed?

Comment: That is just the entry point of the application. If you have a working react app then you probably have it already. Typical names might be `index.js` or `App.js`.

Comment: EDIT: I accidentally left a few lines in the answer outside the snippet. It got removed now. I hope it is not confusing